# How to use the command \hangpun under xetex？

Tags: fonts, xetex, plain-tex

I read the document of *font-change-xetex*. It says the`\hangpun`command
of font-change-xetex provides a way to employ hanging punctuation. So I have a try, but it doesn't work.

This is my test file:

```
\input font-change-xetex
\hsize3.4in

\myfont{Adobe Caslon Pro}{11}{}\hangpun

\noindent Some people are for using hanging punctuation,
and some against. In the end, it is a matter of personal
choice. He said, “I use hanging punctuation.”
“But does it really lead to better text justification?”
asked Joe.

\bye
```

and then it shows following warmings

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   U
\setprotcode ...\XeTeXprotrudechars =1\rpcode #1 U
                                                  "0021 226\rpcode #1 U"002C...

\hangpun ... {\capsslbf }{}\setprotcode {\fiverm }
                                                  {}\setprotcode {\fiveit }{...
l.4 \myfont{Adobe Caslon Pro}{11}{}\hangpun

?
```

and how do I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should setup the document fonts with `\myzfont`, `\myfont` is only for local changes:

```
\input font-change-xetex

\hsize3.4in
\myzfont{TeX Gyre Heros}{11}{}

\hangpun

\noindent Some people are for using hanging punctuation,
and some against. In the end, it is a matter of personal
choice. He said, “I use hanging punctuation.”
“But does it really lead to better text justification?”
asked Joe.

\bye
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get it.